# How to change uri path while repeating in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a question regarding Gatling test framework and scala

Let's assume that I have such kind piece of code:

```
.repeat(100) {
      exec(
        http("get-user")
          .get("/users/1")
      )
    }
```

But what should I do whether I want to pass another {id} (not only /id/1) in uri path?
Might be this question regarding scala programming?

**UPDATE**
I have an end point /users/{id} (GET)
So I want to test performance this endpoint in such way:
/users/1, /users/2, /users/3 ... etc
and seems I'm able to use for that .repeat(100) but I need to figure out how to cnahge {id} in the new iteration.
Actually may be it's a wrong approach and I should make separated request for each {id}

Thx in advance

Comment: You need to be more specific. Can you show a running code shows what you wanna do?

Comment: Added update. Have a look please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a basic use case is of course demoed in the [basic](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/quickstart.html) and [advanced](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/advanced_tutorial.html) tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, seems I haven't noticed it before. Gonna read docs much carefuly